# Ajuda combobox php

Tags: php, combobox

Boa noite, tenho aqui uma duvida urgente, ja tentei várias soluções e não consigo entender

Eu pretendo popular uma combobox apartir de uma base de dados, depois quero selecionar um valor e apaga-lo.

```
<html>          
    <form action="presidente_apaga_utilizadores.php" method="post">
            Selecione o ID a apagar: 
                <select name="nome">
                    <option value="option"></option>
    </form>
                        <?php
                            require("basedados.h");
                            $sql="SELECT nome FROM utilizador where tipo_utilizador !=1";
                            $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                $nome = $row["nome"];;
                                echo '<option value="' . $nome .'">' . $nome . '</option>';
                            }   
                                if ($_POST(["nome"])) {
                                $sql = "DELETE FROM utilizador WHERE nome = '$nome'";
                                $resultado = mysql_query($sql);
                                    echo " Registo Apagado!<p>";
                                }

                        ?>

                </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
```

Comment: Cara, você precisa arrumar esse html, o form tem que terminar apenas após todos os controles. E, normalmente, o tratamento do POST é a primeira coisa que você faz no código.

Comment: Cara, eu sei como é quando o cara fica apavorado, mas "urgente" é deselegante. Aqui e uma comunidade. Não tem ninguém trabalhando pros outros, sacou?
Falo na boa, pois já passei por isso e fui repreendido do mesmo modo.

Comment: peço desculpa, se ofendi, não foi intenção. Não pretendo que me façam, o trabalho, mas estou um bocado exausto, desde ontem que estou a tentar resolver já pesquisei muito e a minha ultima solução foi recorrer ao forum.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<?php
  require("basedados.h");

  if ($_POST(["nome"])) {
    $sql = "DELETE FROM utilizador WHERE nome = '$nome'";
    $resultado = mysql_query($sql);
    echo " Registo Apagado!<p>"; }
?>      
    <form action="presidente_apaga_utilizadores.php" method="post">
      Selecione o ID a apagar: 
      <select name="nome">
      <option value="option"></option>
      <?php
          $sql="SELECT nome FROM utilizador where tipo_utilizador !=1";
          $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
          $nome = $row["nome"];
          echo '<option value="' . $nome .'">' . $nome . '</option>';
          }   
          ?>

                </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Tem umas coisas pra melhorar nesse teu código, mas a resposta atende somente ao que tu perguntou.

Comment: peço desculpa mas o código deu erro.
Obrigado pela sua atenção

Comment: Cara, e qual foi o erro?

Comment: Deu erro na linha do IF

Comment: Rafael, se deu erro o php informa qual foi o erro. Qual foi o erro?
Imagino que seja porque precisa ter um isset também.
Mas mesmo que seja isso, esse erro não deveria interferir no funcionamento do resto do código.

Comment: deu este erro aqui:
Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\rafael\lpi\presidente_apaga_utilizadores.php on line 48

Comment: Faltou o $conexao na chamada do $result?
A linha 48 é a que tem: $resultado = mysql_query($sql); ?

Comment: Outra coisa, tu tá usando mysql_query e mysqli_query juntos?

Comment: deu erro nesta linha:

Comment: if ($_POST(["nome"])) {
    $sql = "DELETE FROM utilizador WHERE nome = '$nome'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($sql);
    echo " Registo Apagado!<p>"; }

Comment: Eu penso só estar a usar mysqli_query